# Как вызвать компонент bitrix:iblock.element.add.form в режиме редактирования?

Tags: битрикс

У битрикс есть компонент bitrix:iblock.element.add.form, "Форма добавления / редактирования".  Вопрос какой параметр надо передать этому компоненту, чтобы он заработал в режиме редактирования?

Например у меня есть инфоблок Новости. Как я думал чтобы отобразить компонент bitrix:iblock.element.add.form в режиме редактирования конкретной новости (элемента инфоблока) я должен передать в код вызова компонента параметр - ID новости или ее символьный код.

Как я понимаю, в режиме редактирования в полях формы должны появятся данные конкретной новости (элемента инфоблока) идентификатор которой я передаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался это сделать, передавал в код вызова компонента ID, CODE но ничего не работает. Что я делаю не правильно?

Код вызова компонента:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:iblock.element.add.form",
"",
Array(
    "CUSTOM_TITLE_DATE_ACTIVE_FROM" => "",
    "CUSTOM_TITLE_DATE_ACTIVE_TO" => "",
    "CUSTOM_TITLE_DETAIL_PICTURE" => "",
    "CUSTOM_TITLE_DETAIL_TEXT" => "",
    "CUSTOM_TITLE_IBLOCK_SECTION" => "",
    "CUSTOM_TITLE_NAME" => "",
    "CUSTOM_TITLE_PREVIEW_PICTURE" => "",
    "CUSTOM_TITLE_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "",
    "CUSTOM_TITLE_TAGS" => "",
    "DEFAULT_INPUT_SIZE" => "30",
    "DETAIL_TEXT_USE_HTML_EDITOR" => "Y",
    "ELEMENT_ASSOC" => "CREATED_BY",
    "GROUPS" => array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"),
    "IBLOCK_ID" => "1",
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "news",
    "LEVEL_LAST" => "Y",
    "LIST_URL" => "",
    "MAX_FILE_SIZE" => "0",
    "MAX_LEVELS" => "100000",
    "MAX_USER_ENTRIES" => "100000",
    "PREVIEW_TEXT_USE_HTML_EDITOR" => "Y",
    "PROPERTY_CODES" => array("NAME","TAGS","DATE_ACTIVE_FROM","DATE_ACTIVE_TO","IBLOCK_SECTION","PREVIEW_TEXT","PREVIEW_PICTURE","DETAIL_TEXT","DETAIL_PICTURE"),
    "PROPERTY_CODES_REQUIRED" => array("NAME"),
    "RESIZE_IMAGES" => "N",
    "SEF_MODE" => "N",
    "STATUS" => "ANY",
    "STATUS_NEW" => "ANY",
    "USER_MESSAGE_ADD" => "",
    "USER_MESSAGE_EDIT" => "",
    "USE_CAPTCHA" => "N"
));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для вызова в режиме редактирования необходимо передать Get запрос ?edit=Y&CODE=ElementID

Comment: Вы задали вопрос, или это всё таки попытка ответа?